# Issue with accessing HashMap trough controller

Tags: android, controller, hashmap

Im having some troubles with returning values from a HashMap trough a Controller class,

```
  public class Controller {

private User user;
private FileRead fileRead;
private ICS1Activity start;



public Controller(){

user = new User();
fileRead = new FileRead();
start = new ICS1Activity();

}
public User getUser() {
return user;    
}
public FileRead getFileRead() {
return fileRead;
}
public ICS1Activity getStart() {
    return start;       
}
}




public class FileRead {


Controller controller;
private HashMap <String,String> userList = new HashMap <String,String>();


public HashMap<String, String> getUserList() {

 userList.put("fredkr", "value");

    return userList;
}



public void setUserList(HashMap<String, String> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
}
```

then in a third class (ICS1Activity) i want to set the the text of a TextView field to the value of the HashMap, I've tried doing this with

testTxt.setText(controller.getFileRead().getUserList().get("fredkr"));

But this does not work and the program crashes, I'm quite sure it has to do with how i access the HashMap, if someone can help me it would me much appreciated (i know its a mess...)

Regards,

Manage to solve the problem i had here, but I'm stuck again with similar issue. think i need to read up on controller and MVC structure. Anyone got any good reading tips, videos or something?

Comment: can you include a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: no errors in the console, but in the LogCat i get this if it helps

Comment: great.  Can you show us what code is at line 46 in ICS1Activity.java?

Comment: thats where i try to access the HashMap, testTxt.setText(controller.getFileRead().getUserList().get("fredkr"));

Comment: can you set a breakpoint on that line, and see which method is returning null?

Comment: Manage the problem i had here, but I'm stuck again with similar issue. think i need to read up on controller and MVC structure. Anyone got any good reading tips, videos or something?

Comment: the best resource I've found for Android-specific architectural stuff is O'Reilly's Programming Android - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010364.do

Answer (score 0):

The Log cat tells you that something is null, so maybe you forgot to initialize the controller?
Have a look at this file: `fredkr.ics1.ICS1Activity.onCreate(ICS1Activity.java:46)`